# VBA round percents

Tags: vba, excel

I have following vba command in excel

```
wbImportFrom.Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(n, 8).Value
```

which returns me for example this

```
0,128888889
```

I can turn it into percent

```
Format(wbImportFrom.Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(n, 8).Value,"Percent")
-- returns 13.00 %
```

How can i round the percent number to integer (13 %) ?
Other examples

```
0,057 => 6%
0,088571429 => 9%
0,15 => 15%
0,048461538 => 5%
0,128888889 => 13%
0,03 => 3%
0 => 0%
```

I tried play with Round and Val functions but it simply does not work to me :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever in doubt, record a macro :)

Is this what you are trying?

```
Format(wbImportFrom.Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(n, 8).Value,"0%")
```